# What is sparsity field in an Autoencoder in caffe?

Tags: caffe

What is this field for in an `Autoencoder` ?
what is its significance ?

```
layer {
  name: "encode1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "encode1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1000
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 1
      sparse: 15
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Is this a spacial type of `autoencoder` ? (is it a `K-sparse` autoencoder ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the weight filler code it is used to calculate non-zero weight probability which is used to initialize a `bernoulli random number generator`.

```
non_zero_probability = sparse / num_output
```

Eventually it is used to mask the original weights generated by the `gaussian distribution`. It doesn't have anything to do with `K-sparse` autoencoder.

Comment: Thanks, but does it mean, the result actually determines the number of non zero activations ?

Comment: @Coderx7 I don't follow your question? The sparsity parameter is just used for weight initialization. Nothing else. After training the number of of non zero activation will change, i.e., increase or decrease. Unless it is already in the minima.

Comment: Thanks, I got it completely wrong. by the way, what are the ranges of values that make sense for this parameters, is small numbers such as 0.05 OK?

Comment: @Coderx7 I have only seen this used in `mnist_autoencoder` where it had range between `0.01` to `0.5`. Other than that I can't comment much.